# When does System.ApplicationReadWriteMode apply and what is five minute upgrade?

Tags: release

From the [apex docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_system.htm) System.ApplicationReadWriteMode is set to READONLY mode during major platform upgrades. Does this mean that any public sites or webservice/REST methods will continue to work so long as they do not perform any DML operations?

Specifically I want to know that they will be able to query existing records and make httprequests to external services.

In the help there is something called [5 minute upgrade](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=five_minute_upgrade.htm&language=en_US) which says that you will have readonly access but only to standard objects which seems to contradict this.

At what point during platform upgrades  and other maintenance windows is saleforce in READONLY mode and at what point is even that down?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the doc is out of date (I've prodded the doc writers!).

Current info from the PMs: What USED to happen was that there would be a few minutes downtime, then several hours in read-only mode. That changed with Winter '12; now, the instance will be unavailable for up to five minutes (most instances less than one minute) and then it's live with the new release. System.ApplicationReadWriteMode is no longer used to support releases.

Comment: Great to know! So when does System.ApplicationReadWriteMode actually apply? Just unplanned partial downtimes when the database is in readonly but salesforce is still up?

Comment: Apparently there are some internal processes that utilize read-only mode, to offload load from the master database.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question...

I've reread the question and the docs a few times. I don't see a reference to a 4hr window though, nor can I see anything on that elsewhere. I am assuming you mean a major platform upgrade like Spring'13? So my reading is that both documentation links actually refer and apply to the 5 minute window [feature](http://www.salesforce.com/company/news-press/press-releases/2009/10/091005-1.jsp).

While the Apex docs don't elaborate further on the standard vs custom object restrictions for read. The Online Help Topic does as you say. So considering the two, my reading is that whats being discussed here by both is only applicable to 5 minute upgrade.

> getApplicationReadWriteMode is available as part of 5 Minute Upgrade.

Not sure if my interpretation of this helps you or not here. It maybe something you need to get a formal clarification on from Salesforce Support if you and your client are concerned about it.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to major platform upgrades which certainly don't take five minutes. I'm trying to determine at what point during major platform upgrades api methods are in readonly and at what point they are down.

Comment: Looking at the link in my answer more closely, it says this... "Now, companies will have read-only access to their Service Cloud 2 deployment during planned maintenance windows, enabling companies to continue servicing their customers all while going through a full upgrade. Maintenance windows will allow customers to access their data in read-only mode for the duration of the maintenance, except during a five-minute cut-over time, setting the new standard that all cloud computing applications will be measured against.". So I think this is saying its up apart from 5 minutes when its down?

Comment: I saw that but I'm a bit leery of taking a press release from 2009 as the final word.  Going to leave this open for now in case someone comes along with an "official" response.

Comment: Yep agreed, ultimately you may need to get the official response from Salesforce Support.